# lxd container. Problem with large file local.img

Tags: lxd

Good day

I use Ubuntu 18.04, lxd 3.0.3

When i start my container, file /var/lib/lxd/disks/local.img becoming more and more. And now size

```
du -h disks/
64G disks/

ls -lh *
-rw------- 1 root root 94G Feb 22 15:18 local.img
```

When i stop container, this file doesn't change.

What is this? What is this directory mean? I didn't search answer in google

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you started using LXD, you configured it by running `sudo lxd init`.
This wizard guided you to select where to store the containers. 
You most likely selected to use ZFS over a loop file. You should have been asked to specify the maximum size.

Therefore, first run the following to figure out the name of the storage (here *mystorage*).

```
$ lxc storage list
+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+---------+
| NAME      | DESCRIPTION | DRIVER | SOURCE | USED BY |
+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+---------+
| mystorage |             | zfs    | lxd    | 25      |
+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Then, run this to get the details of the storage. It will show how must space (maximum) you have arranged and how much is currently in use.

```
$ lxc storage info mystorage
info:
  description: ""
  driver: zfs
  name: mystorage
  space used: 12.37GB
  total space: 200.44GB
...
```

Note that in your case (ZFS over loop file), you may need to use `du --apparent-size` to get the actual space in use. Because of something called *sparse files*.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!
    info:
    description: ""
    driver: zfs
    name: local
    space used: 1.78GB
    total space: 94.96GB

When i cstarted using LXD, i wrote 120 GB. File local.img will increase to 120 GB?

Comment: Since it says 94.96GB, is it likely that you specified 100GB?
In any case, you can resize the space using the instructions at https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/storage.md (see at the end the section _Growing a loop backed ZFS pool_).